# Fox Talas FIT RLC 32 - broken lock and problem with the right leg

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, lock, damage, fox

I just finished my first Marathon race today, it was super cool, the best MTB experience in my life -- but there was a super frustrating part.

Something broke in my fork right leg, and now that one has some front/back play/movement, when I brake the front wheel.

I did not used the right leg lock, just wanted to compress the fork, from 140 to 110 at the beginning and then I heard a quite loud noise from it. The left leg works great, but a rider said that the sound probably came from the right lock part, and he was right, now it has no lock, which is not a big deal, 
BUT because it moves a little bit front/back, feels like garbage :(

It's an old fork, my city has only one shop, not sure if they can fix it. Does anyone has an idea what part should be replaced, and how much would it cost to me?

Comment: Have you tried a place like the [QBP Shock Treatment Center](https://qbp.com/call_up/gimme-gimme-shock-treatment)? It's not *that* old of a fork.

Comment: Well, this is out of my country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service said that there is a rubber seal in the right stanchion, which needs to hold oil for the lock, that was damaged, and because of this my lock knob was not working.
After servicing, the travel was a little bit sluggish :( It does not get back to full travel, only if I raised the front wheel a little bit.

The little play ha developed, and after a few more rides, became way worst. NOW is at the Official FOX service at my country, hope the cost of the service won't be unreasonable high.

Comment: Thank you for coming back and providing closure.  Future searchers will thank you.